# One connection for whole of the form

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

hi guys I have this connection and I have to type it every time when I need my db is there any way to type it once and using it in every button by `con.open();` and `con.close();`

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\db\\it.accdb");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Use a function.

```
private OleDbConnection GetConnection()
{
    return new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\db\\it.accdb");
}
```

Then when you need a connection, call it:

```
var con = GetConnection();
```

Functions promote code re-use.  This code can further be improved by moving the connection string into a configuration file.

Comment: I must write this in a form load or where

Comment: sorry bro I am new in C# so I do not know where to write your code in button or form load where sorry for that can you explain it

Comment: Functions go inside classes in C#, and only inside classes.

Comment: sorry for that I will try it now

Comment: I added in a class and when I call it by var con = GetConnection();    it say       The name 'GetConnection' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Your form is a class... Put it inside your form, where your form load and button handlers are.  Those are functions, too.  I strongly suggest you follow some tutorials on C# to learn the very basics of the language.

Comment: I put it where you said but when I use it ex in insert but and at first when I call it   it say   The name 'GetConnection' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I solved it like this   var con = Program.GetConnection();   and I put a function on program.cs